# UITableView inside UIScrollview Horizontal Paging Programatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Good day,

I have a question about programmatically adding UITableView inside UIScrollView. The structure is like that:

- UIView

  - UIScrollView
  - UIView(contentView)
  - UIImageView
  - UITableView

How can I add the UITableView programmatically inside UIScrollView so when I scroll horizontally to switch between UIImageView and UITableView. Note I am using Autolayout so I need to add constraints also. If it is going to be easier with storyboard please let me know how to do it with storyboard instead of programmatically

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) it is pretty easy to use 5 minutes installation and did what I was looking for.